# Trigger Twitter Bootstrap Popover on Keyup Event in Textarea?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to get a Bootstrap popover to fire when I make a change/keyup event in a text area.  The idea is that a user will enter some text, I'll check to see what type of text and based on that, I will fire (or not fire) a popover.

```
showPopover = function() {
    return $(this).popover("show");
};

hidePopover = function() {
    return $(this).popover("hide");
};

$("textarea").on("change keyup", function(e) {
    $("[rel=next-popover]").popover({
          placement: "left",
          trigger: "manual"
        }).hover(showPopover, hidePopover).click(showPopover);
};
```

Somehow, this simple thing is not working (I'm also using the data attributes of Bootstrap popover for the popover data).  Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bpjavascript/CgRKS/

Comment: like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/6stra/1/ ?

Comment: why the popover is attached to the button to the textarea

Comment: Yes, like that but I'd like to define the showPopover and hidePopover to work on hover and click events.  The popover is attached to the button because the user clicks it to submit some information, so I put it there.

Comment: hover of which element do you want the popover to come button or textarea

Comment: Hi, I just realized I had to change placement to right.  Thank you!  The placement doesn't matter.  But there is another question I have: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20137501/set-twitter-bootstrap-popover-to-hide-after-a-certain-event-then-show-after-anot

Comment: if that solved the problem I'll post it as an answer

Comment: Go ahead I'll mark it up!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
$("textarea").on("change keyup", function (e) {
    $("[rel=next-popover]").popover("show");
});
$("[rel=next-popover]").popover({
    placement: "right",
    trigger: "manual"
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/6stra/)

Comment: How to get rid of that blinking of popover while typing?